# Postgres View Definition (pgAdmin) gets stripped of comments?

Tags: postgresql, t-sql

I have a lot of SQL Server development experience, and I'm trying out Postgres on a few projects. I just wrote a view with some of the commentary I'm used to including in my t-sql queries, and I noticed that when I pull up the definition of the view, Postgres has taken my SQL code and written its own version of the view, without my comments.

Is this just a pgAdmin thing, or is this what happens in the engine behind the scenes? What are your best practices for leaving yourself future dev comments, etc. for the next time you want to come back and edit the view/proc/function, etc.?

I can save the .sql file with my code as I wrote it, but I'd really like to access that version from the object explorer tree rather than going to find old .sql files... Maybe I'm missing something easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of how views work in PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL does not store the string that you used to define the view, but the query parse tree. So all formatting and comments will be lost.

The database metadata is not the correct place for your source code. Use a source versioning system. For view definitions that is straightforward; for other database objects a tool like Liquibase will help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that. I've basically just kept my documentation in the database definitions themselves with SQL Server, and I realize that's not ideal, but as a primarily one-dev operation, it's been pretty efficient so far. Is Liquibase what you use?

Comment: I don't maintain database schemas.